# Non public API validation warning about isOpen: setActiveSession:

Tags: objective-c, ios7, parse-platform, appstore-approval

Xcode organizer gave this warning when I tried to submit app. I am using Parse SDK in my app. Somewhere I read that removing -ObjC linker flag will solve it, but I can't remove it as Google AdMob requires it.

Please help!

Comment: @HoanDang Yes, I removed -ObjC flag from other linked flags and used -force_load $(SRCROOT)/libGoogleAdMobAds.a -fobjc-arc instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had a run-in with this problem as well.  Removing the -ObjC flag was not enough, I actually had to include the latest Facebook SDK even though I don't use it (I weak linked it - build phases Optional).  But then, I got duplicate symbols on Bolt-IOS because FacebookSDK hard linked that framework and I use it as well.  The solution to this was to go into the src/FacebookSDK.xcodeproj and in the build phases change the Link Frameworks setting of BoltIOS to Optional.  Then run the scripts/build_framework.sh
After I included FacebookSDK as optional framework, the project validated properly in iTunes Connect and I was able to submit.